# GUI program not working PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a simple GUI based game that has a button having the text CLICK ME .Whenever the user clicks on the button the total number clicks are displayed on the button.

Here is my code

```
from Tkinter import *

    class Application(Frame):

        def __init__(self,master):
            Frame.__init__(self,master)
            self.grid()
            self.bttn_click = 0
            self.create_widget()

        def create_widget(self):
            self.bttn = Button(self)
            self.bttn["text"] = "Total Clicks = 0"
            self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count()
            self.bttn.grid()

        def update_count(self):
            self.bttn_click += 1
            self.bttn["text"] = "Total Clicks = " + str(self.bttn_click)

    #main

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("900x700")
    root.title("Click Counter")

    app = Application(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your question?

Comment: The total number of clicks are not updating ...

Comment: `self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count()` calls the function and assigns its result to the lhs, instead of registering the function

Comment: I am not able to understand ... Can you please explain in brief ..

Comment: For the command attribute of a Button, you need to specify a function.  You do NOT call a function.  Calling a function assigns the return value of the function to command--but you want to assign the function itself to command.  To assign a function to the command attribute, you need to specify the function name WITHOUT the function execution operator `()`.

Comment: Ok ... Thanks a lot ,now i understood .

Comment: @SahibNavlani, Just remember: A function call in your code is always replaced by the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Please read it from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#a-simple-hello-world-program). In there, the first "Hello World" Example has almost the same code as you do.

The command `self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count()` assigns the return value of `def update_count(self)` to your button command.

If you *think to know* what the result of some action should be, you could always use a print statement afterwards to **verify** what your assignment did.

```
self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count()
print(self.bttn["command"])
```

*What exactly is the issue and where does it come from?*

in the code line of yours mentioned above, you are **immediately calling** `self.update_count` and not assigning the function to be called everytime the button is pressed.